# How to prevent enter key press for multiple time using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress

I need to find continuous enter key pressing in jquery. Is this possible?

```
$('#password-input').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        alert("Enter key")
    }
});
```

Here If I am pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key more than one time mean I am getting alerts for two times. But i need to get only one time only.

Please help me!

Comment: more than one time at the same time:))

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jQuery#bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to bind the `keyup` event and than unbind the `keyup` event with [jQuery#unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) when the end user pres the "Enter key" in order to prevent multiple times the "Enter key":

```js
var $passwordInput = $('#password-input');

$passwordInput.bind('keyup', function(e) {
  passwordInputKeyupHandler(e);
});

function passwordInputKeyupHandler(e) {   
  if (e.which === 13) {
    console.log('Enter key!');
    $passwordInput.unbind('keyup');

    return setTimeout(function(){
      console.log('Rebind keyup event');
      $passwordInput.keyup(passwordInputKeyupHandler);
    }, 2000);
  } 

  console.log('Any other key...');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="password-input" type="password">
```

Note that as pointed out by [@dorado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3830877/dorado) on the comments was made a 'rebind' after 2 seconds, using `setTimeout()`, in order to avoid the end user to have to make a page reload..

Comment: you can also 'rebind' after a few seconds using `setTimeout`.

Comment: I am totally agree.. It most be done in order to avoid that the end user have to make a reload of the page

Comment: I tied an event trigger inside my event handler function. Unbinding my `input` when the Enter key is pressed, triggering an ajax call, when the ajax call completes, I rebind the `input` to `keyup`. 
Guarantees that the Ajax call is completed so I don't prematuraly rebind `keyup` (which would defeat the purpose of doing all this in the first place).

Answer (score 2):

Besides using a variable to store the state I suppose you will also want that if a few milliseconds have passed, then pressing enter key again gives you an alert. This can be achieve by `setTimeout`. For example, here the enter key will be re-detected only if it is pressed after an interval of 2000ms.

```
var pressed = false;
$('#input-element').keyup(function(e) {
    if (!pressed) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            pressed = true;
            alert('Enter pressed.');
            i = setTimeout(function() {
                pressed = false;
            }, 2000);

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: its working good. I spend a lot time for this issue. Thank you so much dorado.

Comment: You can reduce the if statements to: `if (!pressed && e.which === 13) {...}`. and also notice that no need to assign `setTimeout()` to an undefined `i` variable

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable to store the state

```
var pressed = false;
$('#password-input').keyup(function(e) {
    if (!pressed) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            pressed = true;
            alert('Enter key');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.setTimeout()` to set delay for display alert. In delay time, if enter key pressed again, remove previous timeout and set new timeout. At the end of timeout, display alert.

```js
var interval;
$('#password-input').keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = setTimeout(function(){
          alert("Enter key")
      }, 500);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="password-input" />
```

*You can change time of delay to your custom time.*

Answer (score 0):

```
    var pressed = false;
    $('#password-input').on('keyup',function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13 && !pressed) {
            pressed = true;
            alert("Enter key");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".